# how can i prove that every subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ is PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

How can I prove that every subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ is PID?

Comment: What do you mean by PIK? Do you mean PID?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: An interesting question.  *Is* every subring of $\Bbb Q$ a PID?  At this point,  doubtful I am.  Still, no proof either way possess do I.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Then the function $f(a/b) := |a|$
is a Euclidean function on $R$.  In particular, $R$ is a PID.
([See also.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96944/are-all-subrings-of-the-rationals-euclidean-domains))

A more general result [has been linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137876/a-subring-of-the-field-of-fractions-of-a-pid-is-a-pid-as-well), but deduction from Euclidean to PID is probably much easier in this case.